# When sending Xcode project to someone, random compile errors? (Ver 4.4 to 4.3)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I made sure there are no references, and all my files (iPad app) are in the folder. I zip the folder and send it to someone. When they try to run, they get compiler errors regarding undefined methods.

Ex error:

```
Property 'window' requires method 'window' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a    method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'window' requires method 'setWindow:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation
```

Also, the project was created and written in Xcode 4.4 and runs fine there, but is being sent to and opened with Xcode 4.3. Is the problem the different Xcode verions? If not what else could this be?

Comment: None of those errors are "random". They're specific and clear. It also tells you how to solve them. You obviously have references (use in your code) of things that exist in 4.4 but not in 4.3. Either remove those references from your code and use 4.3 functionality instead, or have "someone" upgrade to 4.4.

Comment: Random in the sense that they come from things that xcode generates on its own such as the window method in delegate. My question was whether or not these were for sure because of the version difference or not. I was more looking to see if anyone had seen this before and had a solution besides "buy the new OS and get the new Xcode"

Comment: @VDH The obvious solution is to research the changes before updating to newer SDK, you have the newer Xcode version generated for you some functionality that is not supported with previous compiler versions. The same thing would happen to anyone. Read the error message again, try to understand what happened. Looking for the `synthesize` changes for details will help you to solve the problem but not to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: When you address a comment to someone, use `@postername` so they'll see it. (You see all comments to your own question/answer, but we don't unless you address them.) :-) The reason for my comment ws that "random" has a specific meaning; it doesn't mean "something I don't understand", it means 'Made, done, happening, or chosen without method or conscious decision: "a random sample of 100 households".'. :-) What you're describing are not "random errors"; they're specific errors about missing functionality between versions of Xcode, and SO is designed around asking *specific* questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this was purely a version issue with Xcode.

From 4.3 on, apparently these synthesizes were no longer needed.